# Why number++ uses EAX while number-- uses ECX?

Tags: c, assembly, cpu-registers

```
;disas for number++
mov eax, [number]
add eax,1
mov [number],eax
;disas for number--
mov ecx, [number]
sub ecx,1
mov [number],ecx
```

Why `number++` uses `EAX` while `number--` uses `ECX` ?

What's the convention for dispatching registers ?

Comment: For disassembly, did you do both ++ and -- in a single test (i.e. same file), or did you do two separate tests?

Answer (score 9):

Register allocation is up to the compiler. Usually, it'll depend primarily on the surrounding code, not on the operation(s) you carry out.

Comment: Isn't register allocation specified in assembly/binary ?

Comment: @kern: when you write assembly language, you can mostly use registers as you see fit. A few instructions have specific source and/or destination registers (depending on the instruction set you're programming for), but beyond that it's up to you.

Answer (score 4):

There is no convention for these operations. Most registers are general purpose, and can be used for common arithmetic operations.

The compiler is just using a register that happens to be free at that point in the code.

Answer (score 3):

Your missing the assembly around those extracts, which is probably the *most important part*, else you can't tell if other registers where in use or not (or if calling conventions played a role).

With the surrounding pieces its a little easier to tell whether the allocation was partly arbitrary(graph coloring) or a more uniform linear scan etc. The compiler flags will also affect this too, because both your above examples can be don't without the use of registers.

Answer (score 0):

See all of the other answers saying that it is compiler and code dependent, there is no rule.

```
unsigned int x;

void one ( void )
{
  x++;
}
void two ( void )
{
 x--;
}
```

with optimizations

```
one:
    addl    $1, x(%rip)
    ret
two:
    subl    $1, x(%rip)
    ret
```

same compiler, same code, same day, no optimizations, eax is used for both

```
one:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    x(%rip), %eax
    addl    $1, %eax
    movl    %eax, x(%rip)
    leave
    ret
two:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    x(%rip), %eax
    subl    $1, %eax
    movl    %eax, x(%rip)
    leave
    ret
```